# Что такое "сикамбр"?

Tags: литература, лексика

В пьесе "На дне" Сатин то и дело произносит разные вычурные слова. Например, слово "сикамбр". А что это такое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sigambri или sicambri, *лат* - сикамбры (германское племя).

В переносном значении действительно возможно "дикарь", но Сатин, видимо, не понимает значения, ни прямого, ни переносного. Хотя это трудно утверждать наверняка, персонаж этот не так прост, как может показаться...

Имеются указания на возможность употребления этого слова в професcиональных арго в разных значениях, далеких от исходного, но недостоверно.

Answer (score 5):

"Сатин, улыбаясь, произносит совершенно непонятное слово «органон», а затем добавляет в адрес Актёра – «сикамбр».
Что это? Игра слов? Бессмыслица? Нет, это тот диагноз, который Сатин поставил обществу. Органон – это нарушение всех разумных основ жизни. Значит, не организм Актёра отравлен, а отравлена, извращена жизнь человеческая, жизнь общества.
Сикамбр в переводе на русский язык – «дикарь». Конечно же, только дикарь (по мысли Сатина) может не понимать этой истины". 
Подробнее об этом слове и других читайте на [Анализ первого действия драмы А.М. Горького "На дне"](http://festival.1september.ru/articles/313335/).

Comment: Это всего лишь патетическая сентенция для школьного сочинения... О значании нет ни слова...